# jQuery problem on hyperlink click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In two different views I have the following two pieces of code.

**FIRST**

```
<table class="table-list">
   <tr class="gridrow">
      <td>David Gilmour</td>
      <td style="width:16px">
         <a href="#" rel="/xyz/Contact/Edit/26965" class="editContactLink" title="Modifica">
            <img alt="" src="/xyz/_assets/images/edit.png">
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridrow">
      <td>Paco De Lucia</td>
      <td style="width:16px">
         <a href="#" rel="/xyz/Contact/Edit/26966" class="editContactLink" title="Modifica">
            <img alt="" src="/xyz/_assets/images/edit.png">
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**SECOND**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" rel="/xyz/Contact/Edit/26965" class="editContactLink" title="Modifica">David Gilmour</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" rel="/xyz/Contact/Edit/26966" class="editContactLink" title="Modifica">Paco De Lucia</a>
</div>
```

In both cases I use the following jQuery snippet

```
$("a.editContactLink").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //use $(this).attr("rel") to go to the edit page of the related contact element
});
```

In the first case I have only one ajax call to the server while in the second I have **two ajax calls both going to the same address**

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you re-running the code, attaching the handler twice?

Comment: Not at all. The code is in two different views created by two different controllers

Comment: @Nick: maybe you're right! You made me think to something that can really create a double event attach... Let me do a try!

Comment: I agree with Nick, sounds like you're double-binding

Comment: @Nick: you have shoot the sheriff. I am going to edit the question to report the error scenario. If you answer the question I will mark it as answered. thanks a lot. I think I should stop coding for today :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your code here:

```
$("a.editContactLink").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

isn't running twice, whether by being inside another event, or included twice to begin with, etc.  For example if it's loaded by AJAX, change `$("a.editContactLink")` to `$("a.editContactLink", data)` (`data` being the response), or use a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler, for example:

```
$("#container").delegate("a.editContactLink", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a hack/band-aid, but it will get you working.  I am indubitably sure that you are binding twice, as Nick assumed.

```
$("a.editContactLink").unbind('click').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //use $(this).attr("rel") to go to t...
});
```

Comment: right. After Nick comment this was my first trial! Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is here only to report the error scenario...

I had a controller that return a list of addresses

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult GetAddressBookEntries( int? page ) {
    IEnumerable<AddressBook> list = _manager.GetList();
    return PartialView( "AddressBookList", list );
}
```

In the AddressBookList partial view I simply had code like this

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial( "AddressBook", item ); %>
<% } %>
```

And finally in the AddressBook partial view  I had

```
<div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="height:20px; padding:4px 6px;">
    <a href="#" rel='<%: Url.Content( "~/Contact/Edit/" ) + Model.ContactID %>' class="editContactLink" title="Modifica">
        <%: Model.FullName %>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.editContactLink").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //use $(this).attr("rel") to go to t...
        });
    });
</script>
```

That was the reason for the multiple binding. I moved the `<script ...` section to the AddressBookList partial and everything works...

I am tired for today I think.....